# Retornar registros das 00h até o momento

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou tentando pegar os votos registrados das 00:00h até o momento e o meu código mostra que não tem, sendo que tem.

```php
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM votos_1 WHERE DATE(date) = DATE(NOW())");
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if ($rowcount == 0)
    {
        echo "não tem";
    } else {
        echo "tem";
    }
```

Obs.: Já coloquei a função `date_default_timezone_set()` para `America/Fortaleza`, como também para outros.

Exemplo do formato de data que tem dentro da coluna *date*: **1577380495**.

Comment: Já tentou utilizar o comparador [BETWEEN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso utilizando o `BETWEEN` ou os operadores `>=` e `<=`.
Vou deixar os 2 exemplos abaixo.

```
// 00h do dia atual
$todayMidnight = (new \Datetime('today midnight'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

// Obs.: Substitua o created_at pelo nome da sua coluna
// Exemplo utilizando o BETWEEN
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM votos_1 WHERE created_at between {$todayMidnight} and curdate()");
$rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($query);

// Exemplo utilizando os operadores <= e >=
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM votos_1 WHERE created_at >= {$todayMidnight} and created_at <= curdate()");
$rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if ($rowCount == 0) {
   echo "não tem";
} else {
   echo "tem";
}
```

Comment: Mesmo testando os dois métodos, o erro de que "não tem" ainda aparece. Atualizei a pergunta e adicionei o formato que está a data na coluna.

Comment: O nome da tua coluna é `date`? Se for você deve utilizar a crase entre a palavra pois date é uma palavra reservada do MySQL. Outra coisa, você salva o timestamp?